# Continuity of the function that returns the second smallest entry of a vector

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, continuity

Let $v=(v_1, \ldots, v_d)\in\mathbb{R}^d$ and consider the function $m_2(v)$ that returns the second smallest component of $v$.

(That is, $m_2(v) = \min\{v_i \mid i\in\{1,\ldots, d\}, \ v_i\neq\min(v)\}$.)

Sure we know that the function $v\mapsto \min(v)$ is continuous (wrt. the Euclidean topology), but do you know if also

\begin{equation}
v \mapsto m_2(v) \quad \text{ is continuous}
\end{equation}

and have a slick way to show this?

Comment: You want to show that the sets $\{ x: m_2(x) < a \}$ and $\{ x: m_2(x) > a \}$ are both open.

Comment: This feels like it ought to be true because, if $x_n \to x$ in Euclidean topology, then eventually each of the components of $x_n$ will be less than $\delta$ from the components of $x$, and so the second-smallest component of $x_n$ will be less than $\delta$ from the second-smallest component of $x$. The only difficulty is when $x$ has two components that are both second-smallest, but then the distance just becomes $2\delta$. (Something along those lines.)

Comment: Yes, using that the open rays are a subbase of the Euclidean (=order) topology on $\mathbb{R}$ seems definitely feasible, but maybe there's an even 'less computational' way. What @Robbie said seems more like it, to my taste. Thanks to you both!